# JavaFX: Load data task to combine with progress bar

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, progress-bar, javafx-8

For my JavaFX application I'd like to implement a load Task, to combine it with a progress bar.

I have a Presentation Model which looks like this:

```
public class PresentationModel {

    private final ObservableList<Country> countries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    // Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data)
    private final FilteredList<Country> filteredCountries = new FilteredList<>(countries, c -> true);
    // Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList (because FilteredList is unmodifiable)
    private final SortedList<Country> sortedCountries = new SortedList<>(filteredCountries);

    private Task<ObservableList<Country>> task = new LoadTask();

    public PresentationModel() {
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
}
```

And a Task which loads the data:

```
public class LoadTask extends Task<ObservableList<Country>> {

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<Country> call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, 1000);
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }

        ObservableList<Country> countries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        countries.addAll(readFromFile());

        return countries;
    }
}
```

This allows me to bind the `ProgressIndicator pi` to the progress property of the task:

```
pi.progressProperty().bind(model.getTask().progressProperty());
```

Now I need to have the loaded data from the task in the presentation model so that I can add the elements to a table: `table = new TableView<>(model.getSortedCountries());`

How can I access the data in the presentation model from the load task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task` has `onSucceeded` handler called when the task succeeds. The `value` property has the instance returned by `call` method.

```
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    ObservableList<Country> countries = (ObservableList<Country>)event.getSource().getValue();
    // do something
});
```

`Task` also has `OnFailed` handler called when `Exception` was thrown in its `call` method. You can handle exceptions here. (or catch all exceptions in `call` method.)

```
task.setOnFailed(event -> {
    Throwable e = event.getSource().getException();
    if (e instanceof IOException) {
        // handle exception here
    }
});
```